# Handling transitive dependencies in Arquillian

Tags: integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I am looking for a testing framework for integration testing of my application.

```
class A {
    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Autowired
    C c;
}

class B {
    @Autowired
    D d;
}
```

I have a class A which has some service-level dependencies injected in it like B and C (e.g. Postgres and an internal microservice client). I understand that we can have self-contained external dependencies (Postgres, ElasticSearch) included in the Shrinkwrap part while creating test archive but what about transitive (nested) dependencies like B, where the service shrinkwrapped into an arquillian archive depends on yet another service that I would also normally shrinkwrap with arquillian. What's the best way to handle this sort of situation?

Comment: I would suggest you to run your application in an embedded container like glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of dependencies, you can use [ShrinkWrap Resolver](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver) - this allows you to resolve a dependency with all transitive dependencies and then put them into the archive.